# Ride request widget: Trip information for rides booked through my application is unavailable

Tags: android, uber-api

My app ***does not*** have access to any ***privileged scopes*** but it does access ride_widgets scope. In it, it is clearly mentioned "Includes access to *trip information* for rides you request through the app and the *current ride*,...". So from where do I get access to this trip information (specifically Ride ID)?

The problem I am facing is while accessing the user's history, my app cant differentiate which among them was done through my app. The only unique identifier in it is request_id/Ride ID but while that trip happened, the ride request view is completely shielding my app from any details about the ongoing trip except those which my app provided (like start location, latitude etc)
Is it meant to be like this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible with the Ride Request widget. The best way to find an in progress request id would require using the privileged `request` scope and the /requests/current endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ride id from the underlying service that the widget uses to make the ride request:

```
Ride ride = service.requestRide(rideRequestParameters).execute().body();
String rideId = ride.getRideId();
```

See more details for using the api via [their android sdk](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/android).

You likely should request history scope if you want access to the users trip history. With the ride request widget you can only request a ride using the button or widget.

Comment: As far as I understand, ride request widget (I am using Ride request view) does not use the underlying service you mentioned. It uses a web-view to load a Deeplink url. Moreover `service.requestRide` needs Request scope which is **privileged** to which I don't have access. It is mentioned in the link you provided. And I am accessing the history scope but without ride id it is useless for my purposes

Comment: Can I get a reply on this anytime soon?

Comment: My apologies I misunderstood your question. It is not currently possible with  using the ride request widget to get the ride request id.